# XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is present

Tags: visualforce, javascript, cross-domain

We have a customer who is having a problem with the embedded visualforce page for their custom objects that include our component.

The issue is with the Cirrus_Files_Dog visualforce page. The page is embedded on the standard page layout for their custom object, “Dog”. When a Dog record is viewed, the VF page is rendered. The page then starts polling to see when a process is complete. This polling request is failing because the request is originating from a different domain:

[image: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issue]
Looking at the network tab, you can see that the Origin header is set to “https://na14.salesforce.com”. The request is going to “c.na14.visual.force.com” so the request fails.

[image: Network tab]
This design works fine for other customers. This is one such environment, where the origin is “c.na10.visual.force.com” - the same as the host for the request, so the request goes through.

[image: Network tab from a different Org is working]
We can’t figure out why there’s a distinction between these two salesforce environments. We’re getting these two behaviors in the same browser.

It’s worth mentioning that if we bring up the Cirrus_Files_Dog page directly (rather than embedded in the page layout), the polling is successful and the page works as expected -- because the Origin for that request is the same as the request host.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**

Since Spring 15 it is possible to implement CROS (Cross Origi Resource Sharing) to work around the same origi policy issue.

This is more useful for external domains that are calling into a Salesforce hosted API.

**OLD**

I'm not sure why salesforce is using different domains. But the issue can be addressed using the built-in HTTP(S) Proxy.

You can enable the proxy in the standard setup menu:

Setup -> Security Control -> Remote Sites / Remote Proxy Settings

[image: Salesforce Setup Menu]

There you can add your own salesforce instance. e.g. eu1.salesforce.com (don't forget to enable https)

In a second step you have to modify your ajax request:

```
    var credential = ' OAuth ' + '{!GETSESSIONID()}'; // native VF function
    var apiUrl = "https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/chatter/users/me";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        // for community pages, use whole community url including path, e.g. 
        // https://logan.blitz01.t.force.com/customers/services/proxy.
        url: "https://c.na1.visual.force.com/services/proxy", 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        cache: false,
        success : function(response) {
                      alert("result" + response);
               },
        error : function(response) {
                      alert("Failed" + response);
               },                 
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('SalesforceProxy-Endpoint', apiUrl);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", credential);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-User-Agent', 'MyClient');
        }


    });
```

Sources: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_fundamentals, https://gist.github.com/henriquez/3146782

**Don't try to modify the response header**

Salesforce offers great functionality to edit the request header. It's possible to change or add a headers to your http response. (Documentation: [Rest headers](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm), [Visualforce Headers](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_getHeaders.htm)) However, I tried you overwrite several fields including the http status code, cross-origin. But it doesn't work out the way I expected.

==> The best solution is to use the fully documented HTTP Proxy service from salesforce.

Comment: Excellent answer !!!

Comment: What if your customers are installing a managed package and you don't know which instance (na11, na3 etc) that they will be on?

Comment: @JoshuaDance Got any updates here? ie how do we address this in a page being rendered from managed package?

Comment: @ChiragMehta - no updates. We are still unable to find a way to do this. If it is a static resource type file you can put it on VisualForce.

Comment: @JoshuaDance for me its bit strange, its not working both inline and if open as independent page; and this is happening for one customer only. Seems something around mydomain. For this customer, the request url is https://mydomainname--c.eu1.visual.force.com (but browser url reads as https://mydomainname.my.salesforce.com/apex/...) and origin is https://mydomainname.my.salesforce.com/apex/...  hence the error. I tried same in a developer org with mydomain enabled and in that requesturl and origin is same and its not giving error there. Any clue or advise here?

Comment: This newer answer seems to be a better option, we are testing now. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/100743/50058

Answer (score 4):

In Spring `15 Salesforce added support of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) to work around the browsers [Same Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). See [Spring ’15 Preview – CORS for the Force.com REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/spring-15-preview-cors-force-com-rest-api.html)

This is more useful for external domains that are calling into a Salesforce hosted API.