# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: visualforce, sync, cors

I have overridden the Quote page with a visualforce page that when it loads it reads some settings and displays different version of the page based on a bunch of different factors.  In some cases the visualforce page displays a standard page layout just using .

The problem I am having is that the Start Sync button on the standard page layout fails with just a blank page.

[image]

This is what shows up in the console
[image]

From what I can tell the problem is that for some reason the sync button is replying from https:// myDomain--xm.cs13.my.salesforce.com/_ui/sales/quote/sync/QuoteSyncServlet and the origin is
https:// myDomain--xm--c.cs13.visual.force.com so it is getting an error.

I looked at this [XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is present](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51193/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-is-present) and I tried adding both https:// myDomain--xm.cs13.my.salesforce.com and https:// myDomain--xm--c.cs13.visual.force.com to CORS in Salesforce but it didn't make a difference.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.